# How i can prove Var(XY)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How i can calculate $\operatorname{Var}( XY )$  if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

I know this: $\operatorname{Var}(XY)=E(X)2\operatorname{Var}(Y)+E(Y)2\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)$.

But i need prove it.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just apply the definitions

Answer (score 2):

Begin with the definition for Variance: $$\mathsf {Var}(XY)=\mathsf E(X^2Y^2)-\mathsf E(XY)^2$$

Now, you say that $X,Y$ are independent.   What does that mean for those expectations?

Comment: Yes, but how i can calculate: 
$E(X^2Y^2)  = E(X^2)E(Y^2)$ ? 
i dont have the distributions of X and Y, i only know their E and V.

Comment: The definition for variance is $Var(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)$

Comment: @kludg This is equivalent to what Graham Kemp wrote, after one line of computation.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes of cource, but $\mathsf {Var}(XY)=\mathsf E(X^2Y^2)-\mathsf E(XY)^2$ is not a definition of variance.